# Dislocate [file-location]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

While cleaning up the [source-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-code) tag, I came across this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391140/view-file-location-of-source-code
Which is tagged as [source-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-code) and [file-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-location)

[file-location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-location) should be burnt.

- It only has ~43 questions,
- Has no wiki.
- I can't see anybody being an expert on file-locations

Comment: Sigh, yet another arbitrary burn request.  When you destroy [file-location], questioners will fallback to using [file] + [location] again.  You can't burn those.  Obviously this is *not* an improvement.

Comment: @HansPassant Not a good reason.  [location] is misused already simply because it has many different meanings.  It will continue to be misused regardless of how many specific tags we create, until such a time as we burn it.

Comment: @JasonMArcher So, this is an argument for keep [file-location]?

Comment: I'm in favor of burning it.  [path] probably encompasses all meanings of [file-location] anyway.